# What is MathJax's memory management like?

Tags: mathjax

I am building an one page app, that can load contents dynamically by using ajax and typeset the content using MathJax.

I noticed when used the MathJax to dynamically typeset the contents, even the same contents are refreshed in one region of the page(there is no any other contents inserted), the browser's memory keeps going up.

So I am guessing the typeset done by the MathJax isn't recycled, even when the typesetted part of the page is refreshed.

Is there any way to force recycling the typeset objects created by MathJax, in order to optimize the memory it uses?